# Laravel Scout + TNTSearch: Undefined array key "id" / SQLSTATE[42S22]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'id'

Tags: full-text-search, laravel-9, laravel-scout

This is my first time using Laravel Scout for searching. I have gone up to the step where I need to import the `Model` into the Indexer. However, I am facing error and have searched of similar cases like mine but only to finally come here in disappointment.

I have tried running both `php artisan scout:import App\Models\Content` and `php artisan tntsearch:import App\Models\Content` command but only to receive error on either **Undefined array key "id"** or **SQLSTATE[42S22]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'id'.** I will attach the snapshot of the error(s) below.

1. `php artisan scout:import App\Models\Content`
   [Undefined array key "id"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpLy5.png)
2. `php artisan tntsearch:import App\Models\Content`
   [SQLSTATE[42S22]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'id'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqgD6.png)

The thing is that it is assuming that my primary key column name of the table is `id` when it is not. How do I change the query to make it know that my primary key column name of the table is `content_id`?

Any suggestions of ideas if very much appreciated.